# Showing Form Entry on Modal Window Bootstrap / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a form confirmation window with Bootstrap Modal before user submission.

Here is the html part:

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Company" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Company:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="Company" id="Company" size="50" maxlength="100" class="form-control" placeholder="Companyt">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Department" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Department:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="Department" id="Department" size="50" maxlength="100" class="form-control" placeholder="Department">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Username" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="Username" id="Username" size="50" maxlength="100" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Address" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="Address" id="Address" size="50" maxlength="100" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="TEL" class="col-sm-3 control-label">TEL:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="TEL" id="TEL" size="50" maxlength="100" class="form-control" placeholder="TEL">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" size="50" maxlength="100" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block enduserinfobtn" id="submitBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm your entry</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="entryname col-xs-3 ">Company:</div>
          <div class="entrydata col-xs-9" id="mCompany"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
          <div class="entryname col-xs-3">Department:</div>
          <div class="entrydata col-xs-9" id="mDepartment"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
          <div class="entryname col-xs-3">Name:</div>
          <div class="entrydata col-xs-9" id="mUsername"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
          <div class="entryname col-xs-3">Address:</div>
          <div class="entrydata col-xs-9" id="mAddress"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
          <div class="entryname col-xs-3">TEL:</div>
          <div class="entrydata col-xs-9" id="mTel"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
          <div class="entryname col-xs-3">Email:</div>
          <div class="entrydata col-xs-9" id="mEmail"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="col-xs-6"><button class="btn btn-block btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></div>
          <div class="col-xs-6"><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Submit</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is the jQuery part:

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function() {
  $('#mCompany').text($('#Company').val());
  $('#mDepartment').text($('#Department').val());
  $('#mUsername').text($('#Username').val());
  $('#mAddress').text($('#Address').val());
  $('#mTEL').text($('#TEL').val());
  $('#mEmail').text($('#Email').val());
});
```

You can see and try with this
[link to JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/94gh3bww/3/)

Not all fields are required, and what I want to do is to show only the entry with data.

**For example** in the below image, I don't want the red bordered part to show up.

[Example Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfUY4.png)

The sample on JSFiddle has only 6 fields but my form has over 30 fields. I'm wondering if there's a way to show only the fields with data.

Comment: Wait, you are trying to not show the Adress and TEL field? You can just remove those field from your submitBtn or am I missing something here?

Edit: nevermind, I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove below part from HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="entryname col-xs-3">Address:</div>
<div class="entrydata col-xs-9" id="mAddress"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="entryname col-xs-3">TEL:</div>
<div class="entrydata col-xs-9" id="mTel"></div>
</div>
```

remove below part from jquery

```
$('#mAddress').text($('#Address').val());
$('#mTEL').text($('#TEL').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

I make some improvents:

```js
 
    var all = "";
    $('#submitBtn').click(function () {
    /* when the button in the form, 
    display the entered values in the modal */
    //console.log($("from input"));
    all = "";
    $.each($("form input"),function(i,v){
    var id= $(this).attr('id');
     //console.log(id);
      //console.log("#m"+id);
     $("#m"+id).text($(this).val());
      all = all + $(this).val();
    });
    hideEmptyInputs();    
  });
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
          if(all == ""){
           e.preventDefault();
          }
    })
    
  function hideEmptyInputs(){
   //console.log($("#myModal div"));
   //console.log($("#myModal div[id^=m]"));
    $.each($("#myModal div[id^=m]"),function(i,v){
     //console.log($(this).text());
      var value = $(this).text();
      if(value == ""){
       //Hide if empty
        $(this).parent().css('display','none');
      }else{
        $(this).parent().css('display','block');      
      }
    });
   //console.log("algo");
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Company" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Company:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" name="Company" id="Company" size="50" maxlength="100" class="form-control" placeholder="Companyt">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Department" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Department:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" name="Department" id="Department" size="50" maxlength="100" class="form-control" placeholder="Department">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Username" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" name="Username" id="Username" size="50" maxlength="100" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Address" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" name="Address" id="Address" size="50" maxlength="100" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="TEL" class="col-sm-3 control-label">TEL:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" name="TEL" id="TEL" size="50" maxlength="100" class="form-control" placeholder="TEL">
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block enduserinfobtn" id="submitBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<!-- ########## Start Modal Section ########## -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm your entry</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="row">
              <div class="entryname col-xs-3 ">Company:</div>
              <div class="entrydata col-xs-9" id="mCompany"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
              <div class="entryname col-xs-3">Department:</div>
              <div class="entrydata col-xs-9" id="mDepartment"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
              <div class="entryname col-xs-3">Name:</div>
              <div class="entrydata col-xs-9" id="mUsername"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
              <div class="entryname col-xs-3">Address:</div>
              <div class="entrydata col-xs-9" id="mAddress"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
              <div class="entryname col-xs-3">TEL:</div>
              <div class="entrydata col-xs-9" id="mTEL"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
              <div class="entryname col-xs-3">Email:</div>
              <div class="entrydata col-xs-9" id="mEmail"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <div class="col-xs-6"><button class="btn btn-block btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></div>
              <div class="col-xs-6"><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Submit</button></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ########## End Modal Section ########## -->
```

You can add some classes to know what field did you want to show in the modal and what not to show....  I think could be add dynamical to the modal too...

Add inputs dynamical:

```js
 
    var all = "";
    $('#submitBtn').click(function () {
    /* when the button in the form, 
    display the entered values in the modal */
    //console.log($("from input"));
    all = "";
    
      $("#modalBody").html('');
    $.each($("form input"),function(i,v){
    var id= $(this).attr('id');
    if($(this).hasClass('add')){
      all = all + $(this).val();
      var input = '<div class="row">'
      + '<div class="entryname col-xs-3">' + id + ':</div>'
      + '<div class="entrydata col-xs-9" id="m' + id +'">' + $(this).val(); + '</div>'
      + '        </div>';
      
      //console.log(input);
      
      $("#modalBody").append(input);
      
    }
     //console.log(id);
      //console.log("#m"+id);
     //$("#m"+id).text($(this).val());
     // all = all + $(this).val();
    });
    hideEmptyInputs();    
  });
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
          if(all == ""){
           e.preventDefault();
          }
    })
    
  function hideEmptyInputs(){
   //console.log($("#myModal div"));
   //console.log($("#myModal div[id^=m]"));
    $.each($("#myModal div[id^=m]"),function(i,v){
     //console.log($(this).text());
      var value = $(this).text();
      if(value == ""){
       //Hide if empty
        $(this).parent().css('display','none');
      }else{
        $(this).parent().css('display','block');      
      }
    });
   //console.log("algo");
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Company" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Company:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text"  name="Company" id="Company" size="50" maxlength="100" class="form-control add" placeholder="Companyt">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Department" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Department:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" name="Department" id="Department" size="50" maxlength="100" class="form-control add" placeholder="Department">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Username" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" name="Username" id="Username" size="50" maxlength="100" class="form-control add" placeholder="Username">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Address" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" name="Address" id="Address" size="50" maxlength="100" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="TEL" class="col-sm-3 control-label">TEL:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" name="TEL" id="TEL" size="50" maxlength="100" class="form-control add" placeholder="TEL">
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block enduserinfobtn" id="submitBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<!-- ########## Start Modal Section ########## -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm your entry</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="modalBody"></div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <div class="col-xs-6"><button class="btn btn-block btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></div>
              <div class="col-xs-6"><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Submit</button></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ########## End Modal Section ########## -->
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The first code you posted seems working well but second one has a problem with address field. What is the difference between these 2?

Comment: I figured out from your answer. Thank you!
I changed $("form input") to $(":input") so it works on other inputs too.

Comment: I just add a class... class="add" <-- only show the ones with this class...